# HTML search bar case-sensitive

Tags: php, html

I have this search bar that when a user inputs a word, the filename in which the search is brought up. To help explain this more clearly, I will add the code that I'm currently dealing with.

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="submit.php">
            <input name="search" type="text" value="">             
                <button type="submit" name="Submit">
                Submit</button>
                   </form>
```

submit.php

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])){
              header( 'Location: http://headerLocation/'.$_POST['search'].'.xml' ) ;}
              else {
                  echo "Warning, your request could not be completed";
              }

?>
```

This works perfectly, except for the fact that it is case sensitive and there will also be an error if there's any extra space. 
For example, if I search for "hello", and the filename is "Hello" or "hello ", the search is dis-functional.
Does anyone know how to make this almost ignorant to the case and spaces? Thank you.

Comment: Well if your XML contains small letters only, then you could change the `$_POST['search']` to small letters on the fly.

Comment: Does PHP have a `toLower()` method on strings?

Comment: @tymeJV is that strtolower()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can trim the POST data and use only lower case letters for your files and transform the 'search' to lowercase.

Something like that :
submit.php

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])){
              header( 'Location: http://headerLocation/'.strtolower(trim($_POST['search'])).'.xml' ) ;}
              else {
                  echo "Warning, your request could not be completed";
              }

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `strtolower($_POST['search'])` `$_POST['search']` would get the filename to be lower case.

Using that in combination with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3380159/209828) should do the trick

Answer (score 2):

to avoid spaces use this 
change $_POST['search'] to trim($_POST['search']) in header function

Comment: That'll only avoid trailing and/or leading spaces.

Answer (score 1):

When you search just do:

```
   trim(strtolower($searchTerm))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$search = strtolower($_POST['search']);
$searchtrim = trim($search);

if (isset($searchtrim)){
              header( 'Location: http://headerLocation/'.$searchtrim.'.xml' ) ;}
              else {
                  echo "Warning, your request could not be completed";
              }

?>
```